# fftw double precision to single precision

Tags: macos, fftw, single-precision

I already have fftw-2.1.5 on my system. How can I change it from double precision to single precision and do I need to reinstall it?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's a *very* old version, but if you still have the source then you need to do another `./configure` for single precision, then the usual `make install`.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I did it with
./configure --enable-single-prefix
and it gives me another error:
_italic_ **bold** 'checking how to get verbose linking output from /usr/local/scisoft//packages/iraf/iraf/unix/hlib//f77.sh... configure: WARNING: compilation failed
checking for Fortran 77 libraries...  -L/usr/local/scisoft/lib/' -L/usr/local/scisoft/lib/
checking for dummy main to link with Fortran 77 libraries... none
checking for Fortran 77 name-mangling scheme... configure: error: cannot compile a simple Fortran program
See `config.log' for more details.'
Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: It should be `--enable-float`, not `--enable-single=prefix`. Try that, and if you still have problems then I would try the current version (FFTW3) rather than the ancient FFTW2.